# Adding Multi-String Param to a Hashtable for Splatting

Tags: powershell

I have this mostly working. I am attempting to add a parameter to my hashtable before splatting. However, the parameter I am attempting to add is a collection of two strings.

```
$myHT = @{
    From         = 'me@x.com'
    To           = 'them@x.com'
    SmtpServer   = 'mail.x.com'
}

$myHT.Add("Attachments","$PSScriptRoot\x.pdf", "$PSScriptRoot\y.pdf")

Send-MailMessage @myHT
```

**Of course powershell will treat this as being three separate parameters,** and errors accordingly. So to rectify this, I have been trying things akin to:

```
$myHT.Add("Attachments","`"$PSScriptRoot\x.pdf`", `"$PSScriptRoot\y.pdf`"")
```

> Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '"C' does not exist.

```
$myHT.Add("Attachments","$PSScriptRoot\x.pdf, $PSScriptRoot\y.pdf")
```

> The given path's format is not supported.

I feel like I am making a syntax error here, but cannot find any documentation on the correct way to do this.

Does anyone have experience with this issue they could perhaps share?

Comment: `Add("name", @("string1","string2"))`, so basically add an array of 2 strings (or more). `@()` is a "representation" of array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.Add()` method takes only *2* arguments, and whatever you pass as the 2nd argument will be assigned *as-is*.

In your case, you want to assign an *array*, so you must pass that array as the *single* 2nd argument:

```
$myHT.Add("Attachments", ("$PSScriptRoot\x.pdf", "$PSScriptRoot\y.pdf"))
```

Note the `(...)` around PS array `"$PSScriptRoot\x.pdf", "$PSScriptRoot\y.pdf"` to ensure that it is recognized as such.

While using `@(...)` is also an option, it is generally unnecessary (and performs unnecessary work behind the scenes).

---

Alternatively, using key-based access to the hashtable to add an element may make the assignment more readable:

```
$myHT.Attachments = "$PSScriptRoot\x.pdf", "$PSScriptRoot\y.pdf"

# Equivalent
$myHT['Attachments'] = "$PSScriptRoot\x.pdf", "$PSScriptRoot\y.pdf"
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this makes sense and works for me.

Comment: @MacroPower: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the array values you want to use for `Attachments` prior to the hashtable being initialized you can use the simpler solution of:

```
$myHT = @{
    From         = 'me@x.com'
    To           = 'them@x.com'
    SmtpServer   = 'mail.x.com'
    Attachments  = "$PSScriptRoot\x.pdf", "$PSScriptRoot\y.pdf"
}

Send-MailMessage @myHT
```

Comment: Thanks, there is a reason that I don't do this, though. In the real script I have conditions to decide what is attached (if anything).